# Pytest: making global fixture for entire test run

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, fixtures

I have a following structure of modules:

```
.
├── conftest.py
└── test
    ├── test_one.py
    └── test_two.py
```

My conftest.py contains a single fixture:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def sophisticated_fixture():
    print('\nFixture init')
    yield 42
    print('\nFixture kill')
```

My `test_{one,two}.py` tests look like this:

```
from conftest import sophisticated_fixture


def test_a(sophisticated_fixture):
    assert sophisticated_fixture == 42


def test_b(sophisticated_fixture):
    assert sophisticated_fixture == 42
```

I would expect that running `pytest -s` in the top-level directory would run all the tests using the same fixture, as I have defined it as session-level. However, this happens:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.6, pytest-4.0.2, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.0
rootdir: /home/tomasz/example, inifile:
collected 4 items

test/test_one.py 
Fixture init
..
test/test_two.py 
Fixture init
..
Fixture kill

Fixture kill


=========================== 4 passed in 0.01 seconds ===========================
```

Clearly fixture function is called twice for every test module, and the fixture exits at the very end of the test run.

How can I make my fixture global for the duration of the entire test session?

Comment: Ridiculously ugly solution: make global variable holding the fixture value, initialize it only if it's None. Anyway, I'd expect pytest to have some more clever way to deal with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to import the fixture in the test file(s). Fixtures are automatically discovered by pytest. Try after removing the below line from test files.

```
from conftest import sophisticated_fixture
```

Comment: I'd add that importing _anything_ from the conftest modules is a bad idea.